# IMobileServiceSyncHandler - Override local version

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

I implementing a IMobileServiceSyncHandler. My goal is to implement a "server always wins mechanism". So when a conflict is detected the IMobileServiceSyncHandler should overwrite the local copy with the server copy.

Here is my code:

```
 class MySyncHandler : IMobileServiceSyncHandler
    {
        public IMobileServiceSyncTable<Error> localTable;
        IMobileServiceClient client;

        public MySyncHandler(IMobileServiceClient client)
        {
            this.client = client;
        }

        public async Task<JObject> ExecuteTableOperationAsync(IMobileServiceTableOperation operation)
        {
            JObject result = null;
            MobileServicePreconditionFailedException conflictError = null;
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    result = await operation.ExecuteAsync();
                }
                catch (MobileServicePreconditionFailedException e)
                {
                    conflictError = e;


                }

                if (conflictError != null)
                {
                    JObject serverItem = conflictError.Value;

                    if (serverItem == null)
                    {
                        serverItem = (JObject)(await operation.Table.LookupAsync((string)operation.Item[MobileServiceSystemColumns.Id]));
                    }

                    await localTable.UpdateAsync(serverItem);

                }
            } while (conflictError != null);

            return result;
        }

        public Task OnPushCompleteAsync(MobileServicePushCompletionResult result)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
```

The relevant part is:

```
 await localTable.UpdateAsync(serverItem);
```

My idea is to update the local table with the server version.

My Problem:

This does not work. The local copy does not change. It remains on the local version.

Can you help?

Comment: From what I see if you get conflictError you will never exit your do/while loop because conflictError = null; is called only outside the loop. Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes this looks a bit weird. But its the official example from microsoft and the loop does work. My Problem is that await localTable.UpdateAsync(serverItem); does not work

Comment: where is that "official sample"? can you provide link? how do you know localTable doesn't change? Based on UI or you see the data on breakpoint? Also, UpdateAsync has overloaded version where you can provide conflict as parameter. Have you tried that?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuremobile/2014/04/07/deep-dive-on-the-offline-support-in-the-managed-client-sdk/ -> Section "Handling conflict errors". This example provides a "client wins mechanism" and i try to modify it in a "server always wins mechanism". UpdateAsync has no overload: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.sync.imobileservicesynctable.updateasync(v=azure.10).aspx

Comment: In the link they use operation.Item[MobileServiceSystemColumns.Version] = serverItem[MobileServiceSystemColumns.Version]; in place where you use UpdateAsync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same engineer has a more complete example here: [Azure Mobile Services - Handling Conflicts with Offline](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Azure-Mobile-Handling-6e8538a0/sourcecode?fileId=112778&pathId=1697022823).

In order to keep the server version of the record, replace this line:

```
await localTable.UpdateAsync(serverItem);
```

with

```
return serverItem;
```

inside the `if` block for when there is a conflict.

Comment: Will try this as soon as possible. Thank you